# sapply on data.frame vs vector (colnames, rownames)

Tags: r

I have the following function:

```
func <- function(scores, labels, thresholds) {
  labels <- if (is.data.frame(labels)) labels else data.frame(labels)
  sapply(thresholds, function(t) { sapply(labels, function(lbl) { sum(lbl[which(scores >= t)]) }) })
}
```

I also have the following that I'll pass into `func`.

```
> scores
[1] 0.187 0.975 0.566 0.793 0.524 0.481 0.005 0.756 0.062 0.124

> thresholds
[1] 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0

> var1
[1] 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1

> df
   var1 var2
1     1    0
2     1    1
3     0    0
4     0    0
5     0    0
6     1    1
7     0    1
8     1    1
9     1    1
10    1    0
```

Here are two different calls two `func`, one with `labels` as a vector, and the other with `labels` as a data.frame:

```
> func(scores, var1, thresholds)
labels labels labels labels labels labels labels labels labels labels labels 
 6      5      3      3      3      2      2      2      1      1      0 

> func(scores, df, thresholds)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
var1    6    5    3    3    3    2    2    2    1     1     0
var2    5    3    3    3    3    2    2    2    1     1     0
```

**Why** does "labels" get applied as a colname in the vector version, and "var1" and "var2" get applied as a rowname in the data.frame version?

What I'm looking for is the vector version to be more like:

```
> func(scores, var1, thresholds)
           [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
    labels    6    5    3    3    3    2    2    2    1     1     0
```

To create the variables above:

```
scores <- sample(seq(0, 1, 0.001), 10, replace = T)
thresholds <- seq(0, 1, 0.1)
var1 <- sample(c(0, 1), 10, replace = T)
var2 <- sample(c(0, 1), 10, replace = T)
df <- data.frame(var1, var2)
```

Comment: If you want to convert `labels` to a `data.frame` use `as.data.frame` instead and see if that helps

Comment: Thank you for including your data in this question, but the format is a little hard to read in.  When you have your variables, rather than showing the plain console output, show the output of `dput(varName)` or simply something like `scores <- c(0.187, 0.975, 0.566, 0.793, 0.524, 0.481, 0.005, 0.756, 0.062, 0.124)`.  This makes it easier to replicate your problem and find a solution.

Comment: @CarlesMitjans thanks for the suggestion; I tried it, but got the same result.

Comment: @Barker good point -- updating the post now to include :)  FYI, don't worry about the `set.seed` -- the actual values are irrelevant here.

Comment: Also, I believe the `which` is unnecessary. I can just do `sapply(thresholds, function(t) { sapply(labels, function(lbl) { sum(lbl[scores >= t]) }) })`

Comment: Even if setting the seed isn't necessary, it can be helpful because it makes it easier to be sure our output exactly matches the output in your example.  Since the question was answered, it isn't a big deal now, but it can be helpful next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try switching the order of the nested `sapply`s:

```
func <- function(scores, labels, thresholds) {
  labels <- if (is.data.frame(labels)) labels else data.frame(labels)
  t(sapply(labels, function(lbl) { 
    sapply(thresholds, function(t) sum(lbl[which(scores >= t)]))
  }))
}
```

---

From `?sapply`:

> ‘sapply’ is a user-friendly version and wrapper of ‘lapply’ by
>        default returning a vector, matrix or, if ‘simplify = "array"’, an
>        array if appropriate, by applying ‘simplify2array()’.

To understand what's going on in your original function, it's perhaps useful to think about each `sapply` in turn.

The *inner* `sapply(labels, ...)` creates a named vector of length k (where k is the number of columns in `labels` -- so k is 1 in the vector case, and 2 in the dataframe example), where the names of the vector elements are given by the column names (`labels` in the vector case, and `var1`/`var2` in the dataframe example).

The *outer* `sapply(thresholds, ...)` runs the inner `sapply` 11 times, each time with a different value of `t`.  So in the vector case, you'll end up with 11 vectors of length 1 where the name of the one and only element in each vector is `labels`, which `sapply` returns ("simplifies") as one vector of length 11.

By switching the order of the `sapply`s, the inner `sapply` now returns an unnamed vector of length 11.  The outer `sapply` then does this k times. In the vector case, k is 1, and the name of the vector returned is `labels`.  In the dataframe example, k is 2, and the names of the 2 vectors returned are `var1` and `var2`.

(It might also be a useful exercise to name the elements in the `thresholds` vector; e.g. `thresholds <- setNames(seq(0, 1, 0.1), LETTERS[1:11])` and re-run `func` to see what happens.)

Comment: THANK YOU. This is exactly what I needed. Really appreciate the detailed and thorough explanation!

Answer (score 4):

**Note:** @weihuang-wong 's answer is great, and the solution is in some ways better than this one. But I already had most of this answer written before that answer was posted, so I decided to post this answer anyway.

You get the names you do because those are the names of the things you iterate over. But why do you get a named vector in the first case and a matrix with rownames in the second case? Here is a simpler case that makes it easier to see.

```
sapply(1, function(x) sapply(c(a = 1), function(y) y))
# a 
# 1 
sapply(1, function(x) sapply(c(a = 1, b = 2), function(y) y))
#   [,1]
# a    1
# b    2
```

OK, so what is happening here? Let's break it down so we can see.

```
sapply(c(a = 1), function(y) y)
```

returns a named length-one vector.

```
sapply(c(a = 1, b = 2), function(y) y)
```

returns a named length-two vector.

Now it's the job of the outer `sapply` to combine those results. When it sees that the inner `sapply` returns a length-one vector it simplifies it to a named vector. That simplification doesn't work when the return value is of length > 1, so `sapply` simplifies to a matrix instead.

So if we want consistency we need `sapply` to return a matrix, even in the length-one case. How do we make `sapply` consistent? It's surprisingly difficult. In the end I would just convert it to a matrix after the fact.

```
matrix(sapply(1, function(x) sapply(c(a = 1), function(y) y)), dimnames = list("a"))
#   [,1]
# a    1
```

Now that we understand what's happening we can apply what we've learned to the original problem.

```
func <- function(scores, labels, thresholds) {
   labels <- if (is.data.frame(labels)) labels else data.frame(labels)
   r <- sapply(thresholds, function(t) { sapply(labels, function(lbl) { sum(lbl[which(scores >= t)]) }) })
   if(!is.matrix(r)) r <- matrix(r, nrow = 1, dimnames = list(names(labels)))
   r
}
func(scores, df, thresholds)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
# var1    6    5    3    3    3    2    2    2    1     1     0
# var2    5    3    3    3    3    2    2    2    1     1     0
func(scores, var1, thresholds)
#        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
# labels    6    5    3    3    3    2    2    2    1     1     0
```

Comment: Thank you for posting, this is really helpful to understand what's going on internally!